# Where do I find my custom page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I might get in trouble for asking this but I have been searching WordPress web directories and scouring the web.

I have not been able to find the file based on everything I have read so far.

I copied the contents of a template file called page.php and created a page called page-contact-us.php.

After editing this page, I uploaded inside the themes folder along with the same page.php file I modeled after along with several other files.

How do I find page-contact-us.php file when I log into my wordpress web app?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you did and what you ask, sorry. How exactly did you "created a page called page-contact-us.php"? Pages in wordpress are created using the function "New Page", afterwards that page is stored inside the database, not in the file system.

Comment: I wanted to create a custom Contact Us page. I looked up some samples of how to do this.

I was able to build my own customized contact form uploaded it back to the themes directory. All I am asking for is how to find it when I log into the admin section of my wordpress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a page in WP-admin, there will be a box off to the right hand side (under the Publish area, typically) that holds a drop-down for selecting the Page Template to use for that page.

As long as you've set up the template comment at the top of the template file, your custom template should show up here. At the start of the file, include this:

`<?php /* Template Name: Your Template Name Here */ ?>`

Comment: @GregBurckett, Thank you. You clearly understand what I am trying to do.

Yes, I did add the comment at top of the file that lets wordpress know it is a template file.

Also, I just followed your instruction and don't see it on the list of templates on the right hand side.

Comment: I see it now. You helped, thank you. I sometimes confuse php with vb.net. vb.net is not case sensitive. php is. As soon as I changed the casing, I saw it.

Many thanks for your help.